# Prevent knockback when shield is active

Tags: magicka

When I have the shield (E on self) active, I get knocked back by melee attacks and arrows. Is that just a drawback of the shield, or is there some way to avoid this knockback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the drawback of the shield. All you can do is drop the shield and risk the damage.

Alternately, you can eat the knockbacks and spam weaker spells -  Area spells are particularly good for this because they tend to not be channeled. I find that keeping a shield up and spamming arcane/earth/fire area spells can be quite effective against large numbers of softer hitting enemies that like to hit a lot of knockbacks (see: Goblins).

Answer (score 0):

You could also put up an external shield to block incoming projectiles long enough to channel some elements if you need to do something more complex.